# Linking one google docs spreadsheet to another maximum 50 reference allowed ?? I have More Than 500 Hundred

Tags: google-sheets

I used the following approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14009201/):

> First go to the spreadsheet that you want to import the data from
>   `(docA)` and observe the value of the key mentioned in the URL (Eg:
>   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=ABC#gid=0, in this case
>   the key is `ABC`).
>
> Now go to the cell in `docB` and use the `importRange` function to
>   import the data.
>
> ```
> =importRange(, !:)
>
> Eg: =importRange("ABC", "Sheet1!A1:B10")
> ```
>
> If you want to import just one cell: E.g. `=importRange("ABC",
>   "Sheet1!A1");`
>
> If you don't mention the name of the sheet, the first sheet is used.

it was very helpful
i used this featured and Google prompted a notification that

There was a problem
At this time, spreadsheets in Google Sheets only support up to 50 ImportRange functions in a single spreadsheet.

Any Solution ???

Answer (score 1):

You seem still to be using the Old Sheets:

> A maximum of 50 IMPORTRANGE calls are supported on a single spreadsheet. This limit is removed in the new version of Google Sheets.

[Ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)

Switch to New Sheets.