# Are Google Spreadsheet ImportRange reference limitation applied on multiple instances of referencing?

Tags: google-sheets, cross-reference, importrange

**Since Google SpreadSheets have limited amount of ImportRange Cross reference (50 to be exact) and I may have more than 50. Can I go around it?**

---

I have a Spreadsheet named "Collection".
I import (ImportRange) A:K columns from "Type A" Spreadsheets to "Collection".
From "Collection" I import A:K columns to conditionally selected "Type B" Spreadsheets.

"Type B" write into L:M column which I import to "Collection"'s L:M column.
Then I import L:M column from "Collection" to their respective (original) "Type A" Spreadsheet.
AND "Type A" have a second Sheet in their spreadsheet which imports all the data from "Collection"

There is a spreadsheet named "Graveyard" to where I redirect (import) all the inactive Type A and Type B spreadsheets.
Say... 1x A and 1x B spreadsheet got inactive. I cut their all their connection to "Collection" and redirect (import) their raw data (so L:M) to "Graveyard" and I import the collected (inactive) L:M from "Graveyard" to "Collection". From the "Graveyard" I import all the data to "Collections".

---

Say... if I have 4x "Type A" and 4x "Type B" where 1-1 are redirected(inactive) then my cross reference in "Collection" spreadsheet would be how much?

**So the big question is: can I reduce the amount of ImportRange CrossReferencing with the Graveyard?**

Note: *Type A and Type B represents people who come and go*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the 50 IMPORTRANGE limit, it looks that you are reading an obsolete source. This limit was removed on the new Google Sheets.

[IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

Anyway, it's a good idea to reduce the number of IMPORTRANGE in order to reduce the recalculation time of your spreadsheet and to eliminate the unnecessary processing. As Formulas will "continuously" recalculated if you are importing inactive spreadsheets to the graveyard once the import is done, you could copy and paste values only over the IMPORTRANGE formulas to avoid the unnecessary look for changes on the inactive spreadsheets.

Related threads

- [Linking one google docs spreadsheet to another maximum 50 reference allowed ?? I have More Than 500 Hundred](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24483046/1595451)